# How to delete iGoogle account?

Tags: google, google-account, igoogle

I have tried iGoogle for some time, but I don't like it and want to permanently delete it. But the new products information confuses me. Clicking on `edit (bewerken)` in the title will ask me if I want to delete my Gmail account. But I would just like to remove iGoogle. The dashboard doesn't give me any options on doing so either and iGoogle settings themselves does not have such an option either.

[image: all google products in the new view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be undone. You can Delete your Google Profile, Google+ Account GMail Account, Orkut account but not any other particular service from Google. All you can do is stop using the service, ignore it, or delete the whole Google Account.

Just be visiting google.com when you have search for anything or sign in and not igoogle.com